# wso2 identity server federated authentication integration with keycloak and authenticate to the publisher using keycloak

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, keycloak, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

Iam trying to integrate *keycloak* with *wso2 identity server* and use it to  authenticate to *wso2 publisher*.

| Product | URL |
| --- | --- |
| identity server | https://localhost:9445/carbon |
| keycloak | http://localhost:8080/auth |
| wso2 publisher | https://localhost:9443/publisher |

*keycloak* configuration:

[image: keycloak configuration]

identity server configuration:

[image: identity server configuration]

wso2am-2.6.0/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/publisher/site/conf/site.conf configuration:

[image: wso2am-2.6.0/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/publisher/site/conf/site.conf configuration]

Error I get:

[image: Error I get]

This is the warning I get:

> is-as-km_1      | [2019-09-03 10:28:19,032]  WARN
> {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service} -  Provided Callback
> URL does not match with the provided one.

Comment: Does this error occur after or before you have redirected to the key cloak? if before, pls update with the IS service provider configuration

Answer (score 0):

**WARN {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service} - Provided Callback URL does not match with the provided one.**

This warning is explanatory, I guess there is mismatch in the call back URL. You should specify same URL as redirectURI in site.json and as call back URL in service provider configuration in IS-KM.

This [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+Single+Sign-on+with+OpenID+Connect) would be useful regarding this. This [blog](https://medium.com/@Vithursa/exposing-apis-in-wso2-api-manager-to-users-in-key-cloak-via-federation-1-c1318061982) would be helpful in adding identity provider configurations.